# Pause drawing in an SVG file

Tags: svg, drawing

Is there a command to pause drawing in an svg file if I want to draw the individual lines over time? Can I put a command directly into the SVG file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SMIL animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) to draw over time or with javascript you can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) to add to alter the DOM at intervals of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

SVG does support animation as [`animate` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) and provides [DOM API for animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement). Support for [SMIL](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-smil/) is also available in most browsers.

However, these are seldom directly used because of the following reasons:

1. They are not uniformly supported across browsers
2. They are clumsy to work with

It is more common to use an external library like [`d3`](http://d3js.org/) or [`jquery`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-smil/) and control the DOM elements via Javascript.